# Rhomobile and server can't load Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

I am doing a small project with RhoMobile, I am using RhoStudio on Windows 7. My build.yml have:

```
extensions:
  - json
  - nokogiri
```

In my controller I have:

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

I get this error "Server Error, Error: no such file to load -- nokogiri" , any idea?

---

I am working in localhost. I have installed Nokogiri Gems, I can run this script for example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><body><h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1></body></html>")

html_doc.css('h1')
```

Problem came when I want to use Rhomobile and Nokogiri, I need to parse HTML in Rhomobile but I cannot use Rhoconnect. I was trying some Gems: Hpricot, libxml-ruby, Scrapi, Nokogiri.

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem. It sounds as if it's a configuration problem on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Your server doesn't have the Nokogiri gem installed, or your path to your Ruby isn't what you think it is, and the script is executing under a different Ruby instance.

Comment: I can see Nokogiri Gems when I run "gem list". Thanks.

Comment: But is your server running under the same user that you are? Usually servers do not run with user's permissions or environments.